# Send email to 2 recipients with different message using smtp with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I successfully send email to one recipient using `SMTP with CodeIgniter`. The first recipient receives messages from a form. My goal now is to send another message to another recipient in the same function. 
My problem is to send another message like `$this->email->message("Thank you for sending your info....")`; How can I use `$this->email->message` twice ? Since I already used it `$this->email->message($data)`; . Please help me.
Thanks

My codes to send email to the first recipient

```
public function send_cita_from_out()
{
$config = Array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'xxxxx',
'smtp_port' => 25,
'smtp_user' => 'xxxxx', // change it to yours
'smtp_pass' => 'xxxx', // change it to yours
'mailtype' => 'html',
'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
'wordwrap' => TRUE
 );
$name = $this->input->post('name');
$id= $this->input->post('id');
$date= $this->input->post('date');
$tel = $this->input->post('tel');
$email= $this->input->post('email');
    $data =
    "
    <html>
    <body>

    <p>NAME</strong> : $name </p>
    <p>ID</strong>: $id</p>
    <p>DATE</strong> : $date</p>
    </body>
    </html>";
   $this->load->library('email', $config);
   $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
   $this->email->set_mailtype("html");     
   $this->email->from($email); // change it to yours
   $this->email->to('xxxxxxx@gmail.com');// change it to yours
   $this->email->subject('xxx');
   $this->email->message($data);

    //HOW TO SEND THIS EMAIL WITH DIFFERENT MESSAGE
   //$this->email->to(email);// change it to yours
   //$this->email->subject('xxx');
   //$this->email->message('Thank you for contacting us..');
 if($this->email->send())
 {
   echo 'Email sent.';
 }
 else
 {
  show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
 }
```

Comment: Huh? If you can send a mail to 1 person then you should be able to send 1 mail to another person... I don't get you

Comment: ok, the user fill a form and send me the form data to my email. So i am the first recipient. I want to send him a message as well by email. By using the email he provided in the form he filled. $email = $this->input->post('email ');

Comment: $this->email->to('one@example.com, two@example.com, three@example.com');

Comment: My problem is to send another message like $this->email->message("Thank you for sending your info....");  How can I use $this->email->message twice ? Since I already used it $this->email->message($data);

Comment: Then copy the function, edit as needed, and call that function from this function?

Comment: My problem is to send another message like $this->email->message("Thank you for sending your info...."); How can I use $this->email->message twice ? Since I already used it $this->email->message($data);

Comment: Did you see my edit ?

Comment: I made it as you send it : just create a new function and copy it in the first on.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**html**

```
    <form id="subfrm">
        <div class="col s12 m3">
            <input type="text" class="inputBox" name="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name">
        </div>

       <div class="col s12 m4">
            <input type="text" class="inputBox" name="email" placeholder="Enter `enter code here`E-mail">
       </div>   
       <div class="col s12 m4">
            <input type="text" class="inputBox" name="msg" placeholder="Enter E-message">
      </div>    
      <div class="col s12 m2">
            <input type="button" name="subscribe" class="btn btn-flat btn-subscribe" value="Subscribe">
      </div>
    </form>
```

**js**

```
$(".btn-subscribe").on("click",function()
 {
    var subbfrm = new FormData($("#subfrm")[0]);
    $.ajax({
    url : baseurl+"Home/sendsubscriber",
    type :"POST",
    data :subbfrm,  
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    success:function(res)
    {
        alert("Good job!");
    }
    });
 });
```

> if you want to send same message to different user you can use static
>   message controller.

**static message controller**

```
  public function sendsubscriber()
  {
    $data=array(
            'fname'=>$_POST['fname'],
            'email'=>$_POST['email']
        );

        $email=$data['email'];

        $send = $this->db->insert('tbl_name',$data);

        if($send > 0){

             $config = Array(
              'protocol' => 'smtp',
              'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
              'smtp_port' => 465,
              'smtp_user' => 'xxxxxxxx', // change it to yours
              'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxxx', // change it to yours
              'mailtype' => 'html',
              'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
              'wordwrap' => TRUE
            );

                   $message = '';
                  $this->load->library('email', $config);
                  $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
                  $this->email->from($email); // change it to yours
                  $this->email->to('XXXXXX');// change it to yours
                  $this->email->subject('Welcome');
                  $this->email->message("Thank you for contacting us..");
                  if($this->email->send())
                 {
                  echo 'Email sent.';
                 }
                 else
                {
                  show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
                }


        }
    }
```

> if you want to send different message to different user you can use dynamic 
>   message controller.

**dynamic message controller**

```
  public function sendsubscriber()
  {
    $data=array(
            'fname'=>$_POST['fname'],
            'email'=>$_POST['email']
        );

        $email=$data['email'];
        $msg=$data['msg'];


        $send = $this->db->insert('tbl_name',$data);

        if($send > 0){

             $config = Array(
              'protocol' => 'smtp',
              'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
              'smtp_port' => 465,
              'smtp_user' => 'xxxxxxxx', // change it to yours
              'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxxx', // change it to yours
              'mailtype' => 'html',
              'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
              'wordwrap' => TRUE
            );

                   $message = '';
                  $this->load->library('email', $config);
                  $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
                  $this->email->from($email); // change it to yours
                  $this->email->to('XXXXXX');// change it to yours
                  $this->email->subject('Welcome');
                  $this->email->message($msg);
                  if($this->email->send())
                 {
                  echo 'Email sent.';
                 }
                 else
                {
                  show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
                }


        }
    }
```